# Create Storybook stories in portable format - JSON for example

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, vue.js, storybook

So there's this nice Storybook library, which allows creating component stories for React, Angular, Vue, you name it. But I wonder if there's a way to create stories in some kind of more portable format, let's say JSON?

Theoretically, there should be a way, since all those adapters for different libs should be converting stories to something common, otherwise architecture would be not that efficient probably.

Is there an established way, however?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to auto-generate them from certain snapshots of the state.